# Preview button not working of toopay/bootstrap-markdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig, markdown

I am creating a form with symfony. One field of my form is an `textarea` that I want to make it look better through the use of the [bootstrap-markdown](http://toopay.github.io/bootstrap-markdown/). According to the documentation, I set the attribute `'data-provide'` to `'markdown'` as it is shown below:

```
{{ form_row(form.description,
            { 'attr': {'data-provide': 'markdown'} }) }}
```

Until this point, all the buttons of the editor are working. But **the preview button is not working!**

Is there any idea to solve that issue?

Is that jQuery code necessary for making the preview buttons working?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#MotorsAdsCreate_description").markdown({autofocus:false,savable:false});
});
```

Thanks for your help;

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found the solution.

You just need to add the following js files.

- [to-markdown.js](http://toopay.github.io/bootstrap-markdown/js/to-markdown.js)
- [markdown.js](http://toopay.github.io/bootstrap-markdown/js/markdown.js)

The documentation did not mention to add these files explicitly!

Hope this would help...

Comment: It is written here www.codingdrama.com/bootstrap-markdown/ on a bottom of site.

"...The preview functionalities and html to markdown conversion are provided by 3rd party codes : markdown-js, marked (default failover if markdown-js lib not available) and to-markdown. Without them, this plugin would still work and convert the content as-is, so you could easily modify those functionalities yourself via available hooks..."

Comment: @amine jallouli - is there any way to browse images from the server using the bootstrap markdown editor from codingdrama.com

Comment: @aminejallouli - could you please tell me how can I upload images in the editor ? I have put this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439199/how-to-integrate-dropzone-in-bootstrap-markdown-editor if you can answer it.. Thanks