# How to call .getContent and .parseContent from bootstrap-markdown.js

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, markdown

I'm a newbie when it comes to using Bootstrap plugins (just learned about it via [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/en/skills/make-an-interactive-website/))... I really would like to use this awesome [bootstrap markdown plugin](https://github.com/toopay/bootstrap-markdown) but fail to properly install it so I can call the getContent and parseContent from the `textarea`.

If you could help me I would really appreciate it it - a lot!

I have done this so far (mocking up the example from codecademy)

#### What I want:

[image: end goal]

### What I did so far

Downloaded the following libs (`jquery`, `bootstrap`, `bootstrap-markdown`, `to-bootstrap`, `markdown`) via bower and copied the these files into the `js/vendor` folder

- `jquery.js` (v2.1.1)
- `bootstrap.js` (v3.1.1)
- `bootstrap-markdown.js` (v2.5.0)
- `he.js` (v0.4.1)
- `to-markdown.js` (no version number)
- `markdown.js` (no version number)

#### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">        
    <link href="css/bootstrap-markdown.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/markdown.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap-markdown.js"></script>     
    <script src="js/vendor/he.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/to-markdown.js"></script>
    
       
    
  </head>
  
  <body>
    
    <div class="container">
        
      <form>   
            <textarea name="content" data-provide="markdown-editable" rows="2" class="status-box md-input"_>### Hello World
*This*  **is** the ***ultimate test***.
            </textarea>

      </form>
      
      <div class="button-group pull-right">
        <p class="counter">140</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-post">Post</a>
      </div>
    
      <ul class='rows'>
        <ul class="posts list-inline">
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <script src="js/vendor/showdown.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

I actually think that this install the plugin correctly (my initial thought was that I didn't install the plugin correct which was why I couldn't make it work).

But how do I get the content from the textarea via the `bootstrap-markdown` API's `.getContent()` and `.parseContent()` instead of having to use the `.getVal()` and convert the string to html via `showdown`?

So far I can get it this way

#### app.js

```
$(".status-box").markdown({
  savable:true,
  
  onSave: function(e) {
    $('<li class="col-xs-6 pull-left raw-markdown">').append( e.getContent() ).prependTo('.posts');     
    $('<li class="col-xs-6 pull-right end-markdown">').append( e.parseContent() ).prependTo('.posts');
  }
});
```

[image: Currents]

Which is good. But I want to be able to access via the Post button instead.

I tried without luck:

```
var post;
$(".status-box").markdown( post = e.getContent() );
```

Comment: +1 For finding the library, I've been wanting a good Markdown editor. As for your question, I have no idea but will likely try out the library tonight. Can you post the full code for the text area you're using, ex: `<textarea name="content" data-provide="markdown" rows="10"></textarea>`

Comment: @mason I have now added the full code.

Comment: You're using an awfully old version of jQuery. You might consider upgrading. Also, I installed bootstrap markdown on my site last night and noticed the Preview wasn't working. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435164/preview-button-not-working-of-toopay-bootstrap-markdown) solved my problem. Have you tried accessing the site via multiple browsers?

Comment: @mason I'm using Aptana to develop the site.. but I'm really lost on howto use bower and implement it.. Have tried several different things..

Comment: I don't understand the first code part in the question you refer to. Is this something I call when document is ready?

Comment: You just need to look at the answer in the question I linked to, and at the answer chandu posted. Make sure you have `markdown.js` and `to-markdown.js` referenced in your code.

Comment: @mason I'm a complete newbie when it comes to building interactive website - so please bear with me. I have added a more detailed update of my question. I hope this show you where I'm stuck.

Comment: Do not post your entire codebase. Instead, learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please try to remove some of the updates and combine it into a shorter, more readable question with a clear question

Comment: @ZachSaucier That is now done

Comment: @mason, v1.11.1 is the latest version of jquery on the v1 codepath, certainly not "awfully old".. (*the only defference is support for ie6/7/8*)

Comment: @Norfeldt I think I found a solution, check my answer

Comment: @Norfeldt can you please have a look at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897426/rails-bootstrap-markdown-gem-not-parsing-to-html-on-save

Comment: @Norfeldt is the plugin supposed to submit the parsed version by default or do I have to do that manually in javascript? I want to mention that i am trying to use the standard code given as an example on the docs webpage only in erb format and i do not wish to access any content outside of the form itself. I only need it for the post action. Thank you

Comment: @VladOtrocol not sure I understand your question. Try to play around with Irvin's answer.

Comment: Why not aiming for a more simplified layout, like what we have here in SO or discourse? I mean, at least drop that repeated bottom-left box there! ;P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`e` represent the markdown edit only inside the `onSave` function.

So you have to get the markdown instance, I checked the plugin and it's possible (hacky but possible :-)

If you want to access it inside your post click function you have to access it in this way:

- get the markdown element
- get the markdown instance via `data('markdown')`
- use the `parseContent` function

Code:

```
$(".btn-post").click(function (e) {
    post = $('.status-box').data('markdown').parseContent();
    console.log(post)
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/fdpM4/

Comment: You rock man !
Solved my problem while integrating with angular app.

Comment: @Irvin Dominin - is there any image browser plugin for bootstrap markdown editor ?

Answer (score 3):

Have you download bootstrap - markdown.js file into your work environment.  Check The link of bootstrap - markdown.js file.  The lib of markdown.js may be missing in your code.

**UPDATE**

HI @Norfeldt,

For This you have to follow Below Instructions.

**1**. Check Compatibility versions between `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.js`.(i.e you must maintain `same versions` for both the things.) Because http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/css/bootstrap.min.css Link contains `Bootstrap version 3.0 css` and http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js Link contains `Bootstrap 2.3.2 version JS`.

**2**.Maintain Correct root Directory path.

```
<script src="js/markdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/to-markdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-markdown.js"></script>
```

**must be**

```
<script src="js/vendor/markdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/to-markdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap-markdown.js"></script>
```

**3**. Which version of bootstrap-markdown.js lib you are using.

Check this one

```
Version                       Compatibility with Bootstrap
Bootstrap Markdown v2.x      only compatible with Bootstrap 3.x
Bootstrap Markdown v1.x      only compatible with Bootstrap 2.x
```

**Note**: Download bootstrap files from [Here](http://getbootstrap.com) add add to your html file.

Comment: I downloaded the zip and copied the .js file (`bootstrap - markdown.js`) into my own js folder. Did the same for the (css) folder. I didn't touch the less and locale folders in the zip..

Comment: I have made an update to the question - hope this shows my problem more clearly.

Comment: did as you described. Copied the .js files to the js/vendor folder. Made the `<script scr="js/vendor/[*.js]"></script>` in the order `jquery.js` (v2.1.1), `bootstrap.js` (v3.1.1), `bootstrap-markdown.js`(v2.5.0), `he.js` (v0.4.1), `to-markdown.js` (no version number) and lastly `js/app.js`. I also made new stylesheet links to `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap-markdown.min.css` in the header. It is still not working.. now the Preview isn't event working - it just shows a single string..

Comment: First add the JQuery.js  script file all of above.

Comment: Added it to the `<head>` instead of the end of the body. I actually moved all  `<script>` to the head (with jquery first) except app.js which is at the end of the `<body>`. The result is the same - not working.

Comment: I realized that I forgot to put the `markdown.js` into the `vendor` folder... so now the `preview` button is now working again. But I still can't get the content (as plain text or html) from the `textarea` by clicking the `Post` button.

Answer (score 0):

Change path of these js file

```
<script src="js/markdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/to-markdown.js"></script>
```

To

```
<script src="js/vendor/markdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/to-markdown.js"></script>
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you expect this to make a difference?